# Access violation writing location with dynamic array

Tags: c++, access-violation, dynamic-arrays

I have a member variable that points to a wchar_t array that will hold an input given by the user through the console.

```
wchar_t ** mArray;
```

Then, in my member function, I ask for the input from the user and store it in a std::wstring. Afterwards, I use the length of this wstring to dynamically allocate memory for `mArray`, and assign each character in a for loop. However, I get an "access violation writing location" error.

```
std::wstring givenWstring;
std::cin.ignore();
std::getline(std::wcin, givenWstring);
mArray = new wchar_t*[givenWstring.length()];
for (size_t i = 0; i < givenWstring.length(); i++) {
    *mArray[i] = givenWstring.at(i);
}
```

I don't know why I am getting an access violation error because I am assigning each character from the wstring to each index in the dynamic array.

Comment: Maybe `wchar_t *mArray;` is what you need ? Then simply `mArray = new wchar_t[givenWstring.length()];` and `mArray[i] = givenWstring.at(i);`.

Comment: Your array contains **uninitialized** `givenWstring.length()` **pointers** to `wchar_t`. When you try to dereference said pointer (`*mArray[i]`) - you get undefined behavior.

Comment: @DimChtz , I'm sorry. Are you suggesting that I instead use wchar_t*?

Comment: You don't need arrays or pointers. Use `std::vector` and `std::string` (or `std::wstring`) throughout.

Comment: @Skipher I would suggest you to learn how pointers work and maybe don't use `wchar_t*` at all since you already use `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must store the data in a dynamic array of appropriate objects, `wchar_t` in your case. I.e. you need a pointer to `wchar_t` to manage that array.

```
std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> mArray;   // unique_ptr takes care of delete[]
std::wstring givenWstring;
std::cin.ignore();
std::getline(std::wcin, givenWstring);
mArray.reset(new wchar_t[givenWstring.length()+1]);
for(size_t i = 0; i < givenWstring.length(); i++)
    mArray[i] = givenWstring.at(i);
mArray[givenWstring.length()] = 0;
```

However, there is **no conceivable reason** for such a construction. By far the best way to keep an array of `wchar_t` is a `std::wstring`. Moveover, whenever you need a representation like a raw `const wchar_t*` (C-style string), you can use [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str), for example

```
void old_code(const wchar_t*);     // some old API
old_code(mArray.c_str());
```

---

Finally, I should explain why you get the access violation.

```
wchar_t**mArray = new wchar_t*[givenWstring.length()];
```

allocates an array of `wchar_t*` which are not initialised (and hence contain some random data). Then `*mArray` returns the first of these randomly initialised pointers, when `*mArray[0]=...` attempts to write into the memory at this random address.

Comment: Thank you for your insight on using unique_ptr for this problem. However, is it possible to solve this without using unique_ptr? I'd like to know for simply learning. And yes, I also dislike using character arrays over strings, but I had to because a certain SDK function requires such.

Comment: So, why do you think you need the array for *a certain SDK function*? If a software development kit promotes poor coding practice (such as using raw dynamics arrays in favour of containers), you shouldn't use it.